# Hourly Hosting for Wordpress Workshop Installations

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hosting, google-cloud-platform

I need hourly hosting for 20 Wordpress Workshop Installations. I want to create 20 temporally wordpress installations so that workshop participants can access it via individual ftp access and performance is good enough for 20 wordpress pages. Problem is normal hoster would be good but they have minimum time of 12 month. I only need it one time for some hours. So Google Cloud Compute Engine or AWS EC2 would be ok because it is hourly billed and has enough performance but problem is access is only through 2 key auth. that is too complex for participants. Is there a proper solution for this case out there?

Comment: I assume you mean SFTP access, for which the default user on EC2, on standard AMIs, will require an SSH key to login. However you can add other SSH users and enable password login on EC2 after you create the instance.

Comment: I mean more like is there an alternative in way of docker, bitnami but easy and affordable?

Comment: You could use a Docker image, maybe a Bitnami EC2 image, or just customize your own EC2 image. Any of those solutions will require the same underlying EC2 resources and incur the same hourly costs.

Comment: But there is no easy FTP access without two factor auth not on EC2 not?

Comment: As I said in my first comment, you can add extra users and setup simple login/password access for them.

Comment: How can I setup simple login/password without 2 factor auth? Do you maybe have a tutorial link for me?